# iOs Simulator ignoring Hosts file

Tags: ios, dns, hosts

I'm actually working on a website development and I configured all the needed hostname on my /etc/hosts files.

Actually in our office we use an internal DNS for the QA servers and we override requests with hostfiles because hostname must be equal in both case, anyway.

I write (server-side) on the page the IP address that is serving that page and in my iOS Simulator there's no way to show up 127.0.0.1 it always show to me the QA IP.

I read online that the entry on the hosts file must be wrote one-per-line or the Simulator will not work.

Actually I have:

```
127.0.0.1 it.domain.test.com
127.0.0.1 us.domain.test.com
```

Before I had:

```
127.0.0.1 it.domain.test.com us.domain.test.com
```

Side notes:
My OS: OSX 10.10 Yosemite
Here we are behind a proxy.

Comment: This might be useful, even though incomplete, Yosemite seems to no longer pay any heed to the hosts file - http://superuser.com/questions/829383/how-to-fix-etc-hosts-which-doesnt-work-in-os-x-10-10-yosemite

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin, that post help me figure out that there's a real problem in Yosemite, howsoever I commented on that blog post cause my browsers works good, I have troubles only with the simulator

Comment: Glad it at least helped a bit

Comment: That post has been removed, @Tetsujin or MiPnamic, are you able to update with the resolution?

Comment: @MattFellows - I can still find one of the links from that question [high rep users can see deleted questions] This is the only useful thing left. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/yosemite-10-10-hosts-file.1741422/ I haven't actually seen this problem since, I'm sure it was resolved by Apple at some point [but it's too long ago for me to really recall]